# Print_r ($array) - архив списком

Tags: php

Print_r ($array) выводит архив подряд текстом. Как сделать, чтобы каждый элемент архива начинался с новой строки?

Comment: Сумел сформулировать вопрос,понять что надо а ответ не смог найти ? http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print-r.php

Comment: можно использовать var_dump

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: еще можно просто посмотреть исходный код страницы `ctrl + U`